# Add Default Wordpress Formatting To Data From External SQL Tables?

Tags: filters, database, formatting

I have a number of external SQL tables that have data in exactly the way I want and I would like to use them to populate various wordpress posts with shortcodes.

The problem is that I don't understand how wordpress 'filters' text in get_content() so that the proper 
 and

are added.

IOW: I have a proper WP Post and I display the contents on a page it auto-magically includes 
 and

tags. If I copy that text to my external table and then pull that field into the same WP post using

```
$result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT my_text FROM my_songs WHERE id = '" . $song_id . "'" );
```

...the results has none of the `<br>` or `<p>`s unless I explicitly add them to the text.

How can I take $result above and 'format' it so that it matches the same text from a WP Post using `get_content()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the `the_content` filters on your data.

```
foreach ($results as $r) {
  echo apply_filters('the_content',$r); 
}
```

That should get you the same formatting as in your posts.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters

Comment: Thanks. What I -had- been doing was apply_filters('the_content',$results[0]) and it didn't work. For -whatever- reason, adding that loop did the trick. Weird.

Comment: `apply_filters('the_content',$result[0])`, not `results[0]` as you had it, works when I try, but only if you know you have only one result-- `$wpdb->get_var` would be a better method if that is the case.